# Is Angular 2 stable and mature enough to deploy in production?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angular

We are moving a web application from Jquery to a modern Javascript framework. I hesitate between AngularJS 2 and React.

We read tons of comparaisons and blog posts between the two frameworks and I think we will go for AngularJS 2 but our biggest concern is about Angular 2 maturity.

My question is is Angular2 stable and mature enough to be used?

Comment: flagged for opinion based question.

my opinion is depends on what you're after, i'd say yes for small projects and prototypes

Comment: It's now a release-candidate, number 5 at this point. So unless you want to deploy right now, I'd think you should be allright. between the different RC's there aren't to many breaking changes. We're using it at our company, but the application won't be in production for a couple of months. Just keep track of the updates, and update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
JUNE 30
RC4 Now Available
Today we’re happy to announce that we are shipping Angular 2.0.0-rc.4.
```

We are a Belgium based WebDev company building (for bigger clients) SPA / WebAPPS using Angular. Angular2 had been in beta quite some time already - since we personally don't like 'betas' to go in production (our development), we also don't like soo much 'RC - release condidates' versions. Often glitches / issues can arise. We are still waiting to make the full switch - but personally I'm quite sure Google RC's are safe :).

Is Angular2 stable & mature enough - YES IMO!!!! 
We are just following our internal company policy for 'live' applications not to use RC / BETA dependencies.